# How to record changes in table data to another table with Key and Column Name and Update value for column

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I have table called EMP where i have EMPID,EMPNAME,EMPDESIG as columns and EMPID being primary key. Now if any one comes to this employee table and update  any rows. I wan that update query entries written to another table

```
EMPID  EMPNAME    EMPDESIG
10      NJ          DBA
25      JN         Manager
```

Which has schema like this where ID(ROW),ColumnName,ColumnValue,TimeStamp and ID in this table will be EMPID so we can have one to one mapping.

I have already tried Postgres trigger for Auditing and it works fine but i don't want full auditing  I just want small piece of auditing which does this activity.I am ok to add new column to my EMP Table

```
ID ColumnName CloumnValue
10  EMPNAME     Nick
25  EMPDESIG    Dev
```

Comment: *"I have already tried Postgres trigger for Auditing and it works fine "* - Where is it? Could you post it and explain what's not working for you?

Comment: https://www.dbrnd.com/2017/04/postgresql-create-audit-trigger-for-logging-or-auditing-your-database-dml-transactions-insert-update-delete/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `IS DISTINCT FROM` to check if a column was modified and insert that into the logging table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pr_log_modifed() 
RETURNS TRIGGER 
AS $BODY$
 BEGIN
    IF OLD.empname IS  DISTINCT FROM NEW.empname THEN
     INSERT INTO EMP_UPDATE_LOG(id,ColumnName,ColumnValue,ts) 
           VALUES(NEW.empid,'EMPNAME',NEW.empname,clock_timestamp() );
    END IF;

    IF OLD.empdesig IS  DISTINCT FROM NEW.empdesig THEN
     INSERT INTO EMP_UPDATE_LOG(id,ColumnName,ColumnValue,ts) 
           VALUES(NEW.empid,'EMPDESIG',NEW.empdesig,clock_timestamp( ));
    END IF;    
    RETURN NULL;
 END
 $BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=94f152961a5e7818f24a66722f615246)